# Pig: changing the format of output file NAME

Tags: apache-pig, amazon-emr

I am running an elastic mapreduce pipeline that uses output from multiple pig scripts. Essentially the output of a pig script is stored at a certain location on S3, and since the size of the data is huge, the output files created are named as part-xxxxx.

Now my problem is that one of the steps in my pipeline is copying the contents from two different locations and putting them together and then do processing over this entire collection. Now since the files in both locations are named similarly (part-00000 to part-00342), my files get overwritten during the copy process.

By default pig generates my output files at a given location with such a format for filename. Initially I used to download the pig output files to my disk, write a python program to rename them, and upload them back on to S3. I cannot do that now because of the sheer amount of data.

I do not own the pipeline steps which actually do this copying. All I have control over (perhaps) is the names of the files getting copied). So I need to know whether there is a way for me to attach a prefix to the names of the part- files created by pig.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure you can change the prefix in pig.

even though you've said you don't have control over it i definitely think it'd be best to make the downstream process two input directories. it sounds really inefficient to have to copy the two directories into one just for the next step.

if you really have to though you can do the rename itself using hadoop using a streaming job where the streaming command is a 'hadoop fs -cp'. let me know if you haven't seen this approach and i can write it up as a blog post, have been meaning to anyways...

mat

Answer (score 0):

You can change it somewhat using:

```
set mapreduce.output.basename 'MyDesiredPrefixName-';   /*  This changes the part-r-0000 to a customized name */
```